# How to curry a C/C++ macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a macro

```
DECLARE_SOMETHING(X, Y) {X, Y}
```

Which because of macro callbacks, I want to invoke in two steps as such

```
CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING(X)(Y)
```

But how can I do that ?  I don't really mind if `DECLARE_SOMETHING` exists really, I just want to write something as simple as `{X, Y}` for the declaration but call it curried.

I tried stuff like this, but I don't know how to substitute the `???` with the value given to Y.

```
#define CURRY(BODY, Y) BODY(Y)
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING(X) CURRY( DECLARE_SOMETHING(X, Y), ??? )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what/if anything the macro should return.

Comment: I'm having issues with this as it's before my lunch and it has curry written everywhere

Comment: I'm not clear what your intent here is? Is it that you want to generate a function name based on the name Y and then call it with the parameter X?

Comment: Functional programming with macros... this ought to be interesting.

Comment: I've starred the question, grabbed some popcorn. I really hope someone has an answer.

Comment: Btw [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you ever find yourself in obscure macros like these, something in your design has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: @Lundin Not necessarily. Boost is full of macros like OP needs. I guess their example with `{X, Y}` _made_ you think of an XY problem :D.

Comment: @YSC yeah, but Boost devs are raging dark arts gurus in permanent berserk mode.

Comment: @Quentin I concede on that point.

Comment: @YSC Boost does however serve a purpose as sandbox playground for all kinds of language features. Therefore it is supposed to be experimental, rather than canonical.

Comment: And here I was reading "I **fried** stuff like this". I should get my lunch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get close by ending the definition of `CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING` with the name of another macro, which will then be invoked by the `(Y)`:

```
#define DECLARE_SOMETHING(X, Y) {X, Y}
#define LPAREN (
#define RPAREN )
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING(X) DECLARE_SOMETHING LPAREN X, CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2(Y) Y RPAREN
```

Now, `EXPAND(CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING(X)(Y))` expands to `{X, Y}`.

You can extend this to add as many parameters as needed:

```
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING(X) DECLARE_SOMETHING LPAREN X, CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2(Y) Y, CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_3
#define CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_3(Z) Z RPAREN
```

I'm not seeing an easy way of avoiding that extra `EXPAND` though. You cannot just write `DECLARE_SOMETHING(x, CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2`, because that way, the complete `CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2(Y)` will be taken as the macro argument un-expanded, and as there is no closing `)` prior to the expansion, the preprocessor will continue looking for a closing `)`.

Comment: This is amazing! How do you generalize from 2 parameters to n?

Comment: @YSC There's nothing preventing `CURRIED_DECLARE_SOMETHING_2`'s definition from also ending in a macro name. I've edited to include an example of that.

Comment: I intend to use the call _inside_ a macro, so the EXPAND is not a big deal for me.  That's a great solution !  Many thanks !

Comment: Macro pornography? Or suicidal thoughts? I strongly discourage anyone from using this king of macros. Error prone, difficult to debug and understand (lest say after couple of months).

Comment: It seems not working on clang 16, complaining `call to undeclared function 'DECLARE_SOMETHING'`